# Select second class element via jquery

Tags: jquery

I have below `html` and I want to select each `example1` class so that I can modify them using jQuery.

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="def">
        <div class="pqr" >
            <div class="example1" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false"></div>
            <div class="example1" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false"></div>
            <div class="example1" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false"></div> 
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone advise how could I do that ?

via `:first` and `:last` I can select first and last element, but how should I select the second element ?

Comment: Use **$('.example1:nth-child(2)')**

Comment: Or `$('.example1').eq(1)`

Comment: try `div[class='example1']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child for that. In your case to select the second one:

```
$(".example1:nth-child(2)");
```

This can be used for any child however you need to remember that it is 1-indexed so don't start counting from 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However my HTML has various example1 classes which I have not mentioned in the question. So I need to use parent classes(.abc, .def, .pqr) inorder to select particular example1 class

Comment: Then you will need to specify all of the classes like this: $(".abc .def .pqr .example1:nth-child(2)")

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".example1:nth-child(2)") //this is how you would go about typing out the selector for this instance.
};
```

For more information the documentation on this can be found at [jQuery Nth-Child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However my HTML has various example1 classes which I have not mentioned in the question, so I need to use parent classes(.abc, .def, .pqr) inorder to select particular example1 class

Comment: `$(".abc .def .pqr .example1:nth-child(2)")`

Comment: Then in that case you could do $(".abc").find(".example1:nth-child(2)") or I believe you could do $(".abc > .example1:nth-child(2)").

When it comes to traversing the DOM there are a multitude of ways of doing the same thing.