# How to get the second last element by class in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have some `img` tags which have a class called `targetMe`. Now at a given time, there can be many images sharing this class. Now I am able to target the last element by class by doing this

```
$('.targetMe').last()
```

But I want to target the second last element of this class. So I tried doing this

```
$('.targetMe').last().prev()
```

According to this stack overflow post [Select second class element via jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834143/select-second-class-element-via-jquery), I tried this

```
$('.targetMe:nth-child(2)')
```

But I am unable to get the second last element by class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working with `$('.targetMe').last().prev()` That should be doing what you expect: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pvzkyLr6/)?

Comment: @Right before the image, I have some text and icons. So its targeting those.

Comment: Then you should inlcude the HTML in your question or better a full example so we can see what is actually happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the `prev()` [docs](https://api.jquery.com/prev/):

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.

But in your case, `targetMe` is not the "immediately preceding sibling". There are text and icons in between. Thus we need to use [`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) instead as it will:

> Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Thus it will try to find all "preceding siblings" based on the class, not just the "immediately preceding sibling" and after that, we can use the [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to get the first match only and that will be the second last element based on class.

**Working Demo:**

```js
$('.targetMe').last().prevAll('.targetMe:first').css('background', '#f99')
```

```css
div { margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: 4px 8px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="targetMe">A</div>
Some Text Here...
<div class="targetMe">B</div>
Some Text Here...
<div class="targetMe">C</div>
```

Comment: @palash didn't exactly solved my problem but your approach got me nearer to the my target and now I am able to select it with few modifications. So I will accept this answer. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

please try :nth-last-child jquery selector. for more details, go to the below link

https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/